# Tying up angular controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having hard time trying to tie up angular controller 'pointofsaleController' to a view (index.cshtml).

Could you please help me figure out where I am making a mistake.It is in MVC project built using visual studio.

pointofsaleController.js

```js
(function(ng) {

 var controllersModule = ng.module('pos.controllers');

 controllersModule.controller('pointofsaleController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  //Why is this line not getting executed.
  alert('Here');

  $scope.myArr = ['Mango', 'Apple', 'Oranges'];

 }]);

})(angular);
```

```
posRouter.js
```

```js
(function(ng) {
 // App Module Definition (relies on other modules)
 var posApp = ng.module("posApp", ['ngRoute']);

 var controllers = ng.module("pos.controllers", []);
 var directives = ng.module("pos.directives", []);

 
})(angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Point of Sale";
}




<script>
    function redirectTo(nameRange) {
        //window.location = '/pointofsale/tenantview?nameRange='+nameRange;
    };
</script>

<div class="name-range-screen" ng-controller="pointofsaleController">
    <div ng-view />
    
</div>
```

```html
@using System.Web.Optimization

<html ng-app="posApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js" ></script>
     @Scripts.Render("~/ViewScripts/POSScripts")
</head>
<body >
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Welcome to point of sale by SCS.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Dashboard
    </div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

For some  strange reason my app has modules initialized ok but the controllers fails to initialize and therefore I get the module not found error.Here it is,

This is the error that I am getting from Chrome debugger console.

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'pointofsaleController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/areq?p0=pointofsaleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:1509:11)
    at assertArgFn (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:1519:3)
    at ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:7278:9
    at ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:6670:34
    at forEach (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:332:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:6657:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:6105:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:6108:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js:6108:13)

Thanks,
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js (pointofsaleController.js) you currently have:

```
var controllersModule = ng.module('pos.controllers');
```

Which is getting a module, not creating one, in order to create an angular module you must use:

```
var controllersModule = ng.module('pos.controllers', []);
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you have your controllers in a separate module you will need to inject that module into your app module which would change this:

```
var posApp = ng.module("posApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

to this:

```
var posApp = ng.module("posApp", ['ngRoute', 'pos.controllers', 'pos.directives']);
```

Comment: var controllers = ng.module("pos.controllers", []);

Already have it in posrouter.js code

Comment: I have updated my question with error description from Chrome debugger console

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Brocco has said, there are two ways that Angular interacts with modules:set and get

For setting a module, which is usually a one time thing, this is as simple as:

`var app = ng.module("myApp", [])`

where you can include other modules in the `[]` array if there are dependencies on other modules.

For getting a previously set module, you would refer to the module by:

`var app = ng.module("myApp")`

You always need to initiate an app using the set method first.  You can use get on a module once you've set it somewhere else.  This is useful for bigger applications where you can find applications being set and defined as a one-liner in an `app.js` while all the controller and directive code lives in other files that will now use the get method to refer back to the module that was set/defined earlier.

Comment: var controllers = ng.module("pos.controllers", []);

Comment: I have updated my question with error description from Chrome debugger console